# Confusion about Model and Model View for this WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I'm trying to learn data binding and made a simple C# WPF application just to be able to ask this question. So the app has two buttons, a progress bar and a label. When Increase is clicked, both the number on label and the progress bar increases one; and when the Decrease is clicked, both the number on label and the progress bar decreases one. Below is the outlay:

[image]

And here below I share the MainWindow.xaml.cs, Device.cs and XAML design in order:

```
namespace DataBindingExample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Device device = new Device();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            device.power = 0;

            MyLabel.DataContext = device;
            ProgBar.DataContext = device;
        }

        private async void Increase_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            bool flag = await device.IncreasePowerAsync();
        }

        private async void Decrease_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            bool flag = await device.DecreasePowerAsync();
        }

    }
}
```

---

```
namespace DataBindingExample
{
    
    public class Device:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int power { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChangedEvent = PropertyChanged;
            if (propertyChangedEvent != null)
            {
                propertyChangedEvent(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public async Task<bool> IncreasePowerAsync()
        {
            if(power<100)
                power++;
            OnPropertyChanged("power");

            return true;
        }
        public async Task<bool> DecreasePowerAsync()
        {
            if(power>0)
                power--;
            OnPropertyChanged("power");

            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

---

```
<Window x:Class="DataBindingExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataBindingExample"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Button  Click="Increase_Click" Grid.Row="0" Content="Increase" x:Name="Increase" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></Button>
            <Button  Click="Decrease_Click" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="Decrease" Content="Decrease" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></Button>
            
            <ProgressBar x:Name="ProgBar" Grid.Row="0" Value="{Binding Path=power}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="10"></ProgressBar>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=power}" x:Name="MyLabel" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Label>

  
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**My question is:** It seems like I could achieve to make use of data binding. But it seems like this is still not MVVM. Is the Device class in my case Model or View Model? And for this app how can it be made MVVM? Or is it even necessary? I'm trying to learn things correct and couldn't figure out if my way of programming is fine for this case. I couldn't also figure out what is Model and Model View in my case.

Comment: Device is a view model class. Be aware that you would typically not assign DataContexts of different UI elements in the same Window to the same object. Just set the Window's DataContext like `DataContext = laser;`. The value will be inherited by all child elements. Since there is a Device object in the DataContext, a Binding would look like `{Binding power}` or `{Binding Path=power}`.

Comment: It seems also pointless to declare the Increase/Decrease methods as `async Task<bool>`. They do not await anything. You should get a compiler warning.

Comment: I see; so Im lacking Model correct? But for this application what could model be? Thanks

Comment: For any possible confusion about the model part, MVVM works perfectly without model types, i.e view and view model only, as you have it now. The model would perhaps be the API of a real device.

Comment: You could say it's VVM ;). Or you could say a tiny model is a part of view model. There are also other cases, e.g. when model doesn't require view model. What architecture is the best depends on exact scenario, though for learning I'd recommend you to create model and experience interaction between it and view model.

Comment: @Clemens For the real app, can the Model be for instance Protocol.cs which is used to communicate with the device? Protocol provides specific bytes and methods to get data from the actual device from serial port into the program . In that case I can make a Protocol class which has props and methods for data access which has no direct tie to the UI.

Comment: Sure, that what I meant with API.

Answer (score 0):

I will show you with your example how to implement it with `mvvm`.

1. **Model Name**: `Device.cs`
2. **ViewModel Name**: `MainViewModel.cs`
3. **View Name**: `MainWindow.xaml`

**1.Device.cs**

```
public class Device : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int power;
    public int Power
    {
        get
        {
            return power;
        }
        set
        {
            power = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Power");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public async Task <bool> IncreasePowerAsync()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (Power < 100)
                Power++;
        });
        return true;
    }
    public async Task<bool> DecreasePowerAsync()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (Power > 0)
                Power--;
        });
        return true;
    }
}
```

**1.MainViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public Device device { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand IncreaseCommand { get; private set; }
    public RelayCommand DecreaseCommand { get; private set; }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        device = new Device();
        device.Power = 0;
        IncreaseCommand = new RelayCommand(IncreaseMethod);
        DecreaseCommand = new RelayCommand(DecreaseMethod);
    }

    private async void IncreaseMethod(object parameter)
    {
        bool flag = await device.IncreasePowerAsync();
    }
    private async void DecreaseMethod(object parameter)
    {
        bool flag = await device.DecreasePowerAsync();
    }
}
```

**3.MainWindow.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   public MainWindow()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       DataContext = new MainViewModel();
   }
}
```

**4.MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="DataBindingExample.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataBindingExample" mc:Ignorable="d" Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
  <Grid>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Increase" x:Name="Increase" Command="{Binding IncreaseCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" x:Name="Decrease" Content="Decrease" Command="{Binding DecreaseCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></Button>

    <ProgressBar x:Name="ProgBar" Grid.Row="0" Value="{Binding Path=device.Power}" Maximum="100" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="10"></ProgressBar>
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=device.Power}" x:Name="MyLabel" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Label>

  </Grid>
</Window>
```

**5.RelayCommand.cs** To connect Window `buttons` to methods inside the ViewModel

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
   readonly Action<object> _execute;
   readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

   public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
   {
     if (execute == null)
     {
        throw new NullReferenceException("execute");
     }
     else
     {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
     }
   }

   public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
   public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
   {
      if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
         CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
   }

   public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null)
   {

   }
   public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
   {
      return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
   }

   public void Execute(object parameter)
   {
      _execute.Invoke(parameter);
   }
}
```